# Blender 2.91 Linear Animation acting like a Bezier

Tags: animation, armature, bezier-curves, interpolation

i got a Weird Problem since i updated to 2.91, then i try to loop my animation by changing the interpolation type to Linear the Result almost looks the same as Bezier, i did try it with a new scene and a simple Cube with a Armature and a single bone. the Animation seem to be faster with Linear but the end and start from every key frame is still eased in/out.

Comment: Can't reproduce this on my computer. The best would be to upload your file where this happens. Follow this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=7WkmRPQ8" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7WkmRPQ8/)

Comment: hmmm...really weird. i tried it in 2.81 and it looks same....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using *Quaternion (WXYZ) Rotation*, which is the default setting for bones in *Pose Mode*. Set the Rotation method to *XYZ Euler* and animate the *Y Rotation* from 0° to 360°.

You should also set the last keyframe with 360° on frame 101 instead of 100 if you want a looped animation from frames 1-100, because 0° = 360° and the animation would look as if it pauses for one frame.

Comment: So this seem to work but why is Quaternion so smoothed out and Euler isnt? wouldn't it be more practical to use a Quaternion so i have axis lock in my Animation.

Comment: It's not that the interpolation is smoothed, it's just that the way quaternion works result in a motion that, unlike euler, doesn't follow the 3D axes per say.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason why it never occurred to me before was because i was using less keyframes for my Animation, it seem to be the case that Quaternions starting to slow down and wooble a lot then your animation is longer than 100 Keyframes. So for the Future i will use Euler in Technical Animations for persistent Animation Cycles.